# Returning a multidimensional array as json response

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array, pagination

I am working on a jquery pagination where I have Json Response to return data to be loaded in specific page and other supporting binding elements values. For this I need to return a two dimensional array as a Json response on each page clicks. I have declared two dimensional array and returning it like below which I think am doing in a wrong way that is needed to be corrected.

Code in my php page:

```
     header("Content-Type: application/json");   
 dataset array from which pagination will select the page data:

    $data = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j",);

    2 dimensional array that I wish to return as response:

$response_multi = array(
    $currentPage,
    $hasNextPage,
    $hasPreviousPage,
    $maxPage,
    $dataCount,
    $dataResponse = array($pageSize),
    $pageSize   
);
    ######### variables and array within $response_multi array will be set and the return section is like ############

    echo json_encode($response_multi );
```

It's not working. Anybody please! Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: declare $pagesize outsided as array and pass it like this  $dataResponse = $pageSize,

Comment: What are the values of all the other variables inside your multidimensional array? This should have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
$pageSize = array(1,2,3,4)


$response_multi[] =  $currentPage;
$response_multi[] =  $hasNextPage;
$response_multi[] =  $hasPreviousPage;
$response_multi[] =  $maxPage;
$response_multi[] =  $dataCount;
$response_multi['dataResponse'] =  $pageSize;
$response_multi[] =  $pageSize;

echo json_encode($response_multi);
```

Comment: Thanks @sundar, that worked except i had to use $response_multi[]= $dataResponse to set an array inside that array.:)